# how to add List<List<MyClass>>() as DataGrid.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, datagrid

## The Problem

if i have such a List let's call it `Rows` and i wan't to add like `myDataGrid.ItemsSource = Rows;` 
than i get in all Columns the first myClass per subList

it looks like

```
 Column0  |  Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3

firstrow0 | firstrow0 | firstrow0 | firstrow0
firstrow1 | firstrow1 | firstrow1 | firstrow1
firstrow2 | firstrow2 | firstrow2 | firstrow2
```

## The Code

### XAML

```
    <DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>                    
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vmv:myClass}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmv:myClass}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                  
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vmv:myClass}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

### behind

```
        var list = new List<List<myClass>>();

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            var myRow = new List<myClass>();
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
                myRow.Add(new myClass() { ID = col, Name = "Row"+row +" Column:" + col });
            list.Add(myRow);
        }

        myDataGrid.ItemsSource = list.AsEnumerable<IEnumerable>();
```

### myClass

```
public class myClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other stuff
}
```

### The Question

What do i need to get this working. Do i need to cast it in some way? Do i need some other `Object` as a `List<>`?
Anything that could help is greatly appreciated!

### EDIT

in RL Code i will not be able to change the DataTemplate part
because it part of `XAMLFile` that will created by my company so it will fit so parameters but original it will only be for printing. I only load it to `Find("ItemTemplate")` => cast it as `DataTemplate` and us it to provide a WYSIWYG 
for the `DataGridCell` because the Width and Height will be different from `PrintTemplate` to `PrintTemplate`

### Solution

the following code is the solution for my specific Problem take also a look at michele Answer

```
        #region example Datacreation
        var list = new List<IEnumerable>();

        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
            var myRow = new List<myClass>();
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                myRow.Add(new myClass() { ID = col, Name = "Row" + row + " Column:" + col });
            }
            list.Add(myRow);
        }
        #endregion

        #region FileToDataTemplate
        var myXamlFile = "<Window xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' "
                   + "xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' "
                   + "xmlns:vmv='clr-namespace:toDataGrid;assembly=toDataGrid' " //namespace
                   + "SizeToContent='WidthAndHeight'>"
                   + "<Window.Resources>"
                       + "<DataTemplate x:Name='myFileCellTemplate' DataType='{x:Type vmv:myClass}'>"
                            + "<TextBlock Text='{Binding Name}'/>"
                        + "</DataTemplate>"
                   + "</Window.Resources>"
            // some stuff
             + "</Window>";

        Window myWindow = (Window)XamlReader.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(myXamlFile)));
        myWindow.Close();

        DataTemplate myCellTemplate = (DataTemplate)myWindow.FindName("myFileCellTemplate");
        #endregion

        DataGrid myDataGrid = new DataGrid();

        #region dyn DataGridcreation
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            #region HelperDataTemplatecreation
            var myResourceDictionaryString = "<ResourceDictionary xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' "
                                                                   + "xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' "
                                                                   + "xmlns:vmv='clr-namespace:toDataGrid;assembly=toDataGrid'>" //namespace

                                                                       + "<DataTemplate DataType='{x:Type vmv:myClass}'>"
                                                                           + "<Label Content='{Binding [" + col + "]}'/>"
                                                                       + "</DataTemplate>"
                                                  + "</ResourceDictionary> ";

            ResourceDictionary ResDic = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(myResourceDictionaryString)));

            DataTemplate HelpDTemp = (DataTemplate)ResDic[ResDic.Keys.Cast<Object>().First()];
            #endregion

            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();


            templateColumn.Header = col;

            templateColumn.CellTemplate = HelpDTemp;
            templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = HelpDTemp;

            myDataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
        }
        #endregion


        myDataGrid.Resources.Add(new DataTemplateKey(typeof(myClass)), myCellTemplate);
        myDataGrid.ItemsSource = list.AsEnumerable<IEnumerable>();
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950312/how-to-add-data-to-a-wpf-datagrid-programatically ?

Comment: I'll try it maybe it works how i exspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shoes I will generate all the DataGridColumns programmatically (as suggested in the comments) so you can assign the correct DataContext to every cell and everything will be really dynamic.

But, if your question it's only about a `DataBinding` problem, your example will work if you change your TextBlock DataBinding expression to:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].Name}"/>
```

for the first data template, `[1].Name` and `[2].Name` for the other two DataTemplates.
That's will work beacuse your row DataContext is a `List<T>`, so adding `[#]` to your DataBinding expression will set the data context of every cell to the correct object.

EDIT - Based on comments below: How to create datagridcolumn programmatically using a given datattemplate from resources.

**In code behind**

```
//In your example you have 5 columns    
for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
{
  DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
  //Basically i will wrap your DataTemplate in a ContentPresenter
  //The ContentProperty is set to point to the correct element of your list                  
  var factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
  factory.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", c.ToString())));
  factory.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty, this.FindResource("YourTemplateName") as DataTemplate);
  column.SetValue(DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateProperty, new DataTemplate { VisualTree = factory });
  myDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: how can i do this in code? because `myDatagrid` it's in my original code generated in code an Bounded to `my View` per Property

Comment: I'm sure I've done this in the recent past. I'll search for a snippet of code and i'll update the answer asap.

Comment: thanks, but i just remembered i think i can't do it that way because my `DataTemplate` is fixed (i load it from a `File`) so i think i'm not able to change this with out rebuild the `DataTemplate`

Comment: <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vmv:myClass}"> is loaded from a file?

Comment: Ok, in any case my implementation was based on this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009021/assign-binding-path-at-runtime-in-wpf-datatemplate

Comment: maybe i could add a `DataTemplate` that will select `[0]` and than in this `DataTemplate` i could ad my `DataTemplate` from the `File` what do you think?

Comment: i can't get this to work i don't know whats wrong @michele could you please provide your code example which you were talking.