# What is the best Table provided to manipulate (like swaping cells rows, columns) Data

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on an WPF project using the MVVM-Pattern.

Until now everything works fine but now I'm facing an ugly design problem.
To display my Data I use a `DataGrid` like anyone else but my `ItemsSource` is an `List<List<MyClass>>` because I need to display the whole object via an `DataTemplate`. On my `DatagridCells` I get this also to work but now I need to reorder my non existent columns after some UI-Entries, but this will be a pain so want to know what kind of table-like class you would use to provide these objects?

What I need to be able to do (in easy to program):

- access each cell
- reorder/swap columns
- reorder/swap rows

## Edit:

After is now see that it's not that easy to understand what I actually do here some further information.

For they don't understand what a `List<List<MyClass>>` is it is nothing more than a `MyClass[,]`

**@Charleh**
`"How do you reorder non-existent columns?"`
 brilliant question ... if you would read properly you would see that I need an new typeof Data Provider aka a real Table and not my `List<List<MyClass>>` who hasn't Columns because if you have such a `List<List<MyClass>>` lets named  `MyListLister` your `MyListLister[0]` would be an Row and `MyListLister[0][0]` would be an Cell

`You mean you have a single column because you are using a data template to show the object?`
I create my DataGrid per code because it need to be dynamic because the User can change the style of the whole DataGrid depending on a Combobox selection after each selection I need to recreate my DataGrid and modify my MyListLister but to use it as ItemsSoucre I have to do [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960738/how-to-add-listlistmyclass-as-datagrid-itemssource)

**@HighCore**
`Post the relevant XAML`
there isn't really some useful xaml so I will provide a simple example after some rest

## Edit 2:

sorry for the delay with the example but here it is my simple example

### MainWindow

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="TableToDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Label Name="theElement"/>
</Window>
```

**.CS**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    theElement.Content = new MyUsercontrol();
}
```

### MyUsercontrol

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TableToDataGrid.MyUsercontrol"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vmv="clr-namespace:TableToDataGrid">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyCellTemplate"  DataType="{x:Type vmv:myClass}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Label Name="AddYourDataGridHere"/>
</UserControl>
```

**.CS**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TableToDataGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MyUsercontrol.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyUsercontrol : UserControl
    {
        DataGrid myDataGrid = new DataGrid();
        public MyUsercontrol()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var list = new List<List<myClass>>();

            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                var myRow = new List<myClass>();
                for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
                    myRow.Add(new myClass() { ID = col, Name = "Row" + row + " Column:" + col });
                list.Add(myRow);
            }

            #region the hack 
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
            {
                DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();                
                var factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
                factory.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", c.ToString())));
                factory.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty, this.FindResource("MyCellTemplate") as DataTemplate);
                column.SetValue(DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateProperty, new DataTemplate { VisualTree = factory });
                myDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            #endregion the hack 

            myDataGrid.ItemsSource = list.AsEnumerable<IEnumerable>();
            myDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            AddYourDataGridHere.Content = myDataGrid;
        }
    }
}
```

### myClass.cs

```
namespace TableToDataGrid
{
    public class myClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see the result is an ordinary table. and does anybody know how to provide the same result in a much easier way (`ItemsSource`) where I will be able to do my 3 Points from above ?

Comment: How do you reorder non-existent columns? You mean you have a single column because you are using a data template to show the object? Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: Post the relevant XAML, the Data Items and a screenshot of what you have versus what you need. Otherwise it's really hard to understand the problem and help you.

Comment: @HighCore some ideas or new questions after i'm answered your current question

Answer (score 2):

WiiMaxx,

It sounds like you are trying to display a deep object graph linearly, which can be quite troublesome with a DataGrid. I was able to tackle this challenge by inheriting from DynamicObject on my entity base class (I'm using Entity Framework in this case). If you aren't familiar with DynamicObject you can read about it at this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx

Essentially what it allows you to do is use a property bag to store dynamic properties that will come and go on your object at runtime using the dynamic type. This is a beautiful solution when you need to flatten your graph out for display in a datagrid. You just need to make sure to override the TryGetMember and TrySetMember methods. This is especially beautiful when coupled with databinding, because you can add/remove members at runtime and through databinding, WPF will attempt to access/update these members via those overriden methods.

```
public class EntityBase : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (!HasProperty(propertyName))
        {
            return;
        }

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public bool HasProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        // Verify that the property name matches a real,  
        // public, instance property on this object.
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    #endregion


    #region Ctor

    public EntityBase()
    {
        this.DynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    #endregion


    #region DynamicObject Overrides

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

        return this.DynamicProperties.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        this.DynamicProperties[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(binder.Name);

        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, using this as your base class for your model types you can add/remove members at runtime and still leverage WPF databinding.

So next we need to flatten our graph. The base class below ViewModelBase simply implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class YourViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private YourDeepObjectGraphClass _instance;
    public YourDeepObjectGraphClass Instance
    {
        get { return _yourClass; }
        set
        {
            _yourClass = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Instance");
        }
    }

    public void FlattenGraph()
    {
        foreach (IEnumerable<DeepObjectGraphType> t in Instance.List)
        {
            ((dynamic)Instance).YourDynamicProperty = t.SomeProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your view you could setup a binding on a control (ItemsControl, DataGrid) to 'YourDynamicProperty' and WPF would render it out for you provided you've called FlattenGraph after InitializeComponent has been called in your code behind.

I hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: maybe i didn't understand you correctly because i'm displaying UI's in each DataGridCell and non object graph. Also after some testing i can say i will end up with the same problems like i do before (see my 3 Points in my question)