# Is it possible to bind a List<Object> which contains List<String> to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My question is how to bind a `List<Object>` ( Which contains a `List<String>` ) to a DataGrid in WPF

Lets say the Class looks like this

```
Class Student
{
         String Name;
         List<String> Marks;
}
```

Lets say i have `List<Student>` but how would i bind this to a Data Grid in the Data Source.

I am sure this, `DataGrid.DataSource=List<Student>` wouldn't work as expected.

This is how i want

[image]

Comment: Which student's marks you want to show?? My question do you want to bind the current selected student's mark??

Comment: I have 5 students in the List<Student> object and each having 5 subject marks.

Comment: Do you want to show all students and theri names at the same time or anyone student's mark based on any selection???

Comment: you can't. DataGrid's source is a list（two dimension）. you can use listview ,and creat DataGrid in it.bind List<Student> to listview and bind Marks to DataGrid.

Comment: @Sivasubramanian No all the students.

Comment: could you post a screen how you want to see it?

Comment: @pushpraj Check the image in the question

Comment: @UsualSuspect if you searching for some sort of autogeneration take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14961285/1993545)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you go

```xml
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                Header="Name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Marks[0]}"
                                Header="Mark1" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Marks[1]}"
                                Header="Mark2" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Marks[2]}"
                                Header="Mark3" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

also change class as

```
    class Student
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public List<String> Marks { get; set; }
    }
```

note I made public properties for your variables

result

[image: sample]

**Variable Columns**

you can have variable number of columns but not for each row

method1 hard-code maximum columns in xaml, so if a column does not have a value for that row it will remain empty

eg

[image: grid sample 2]

I have added another column to demonstrate clearly

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Marks[3]}"
                    Header="Mark4" />
```

other approach involve to generate columns at run-time via code behind or via help of attached properties

Comment: The number of marks could be changing. Its not always three marks always

Comment: i hope every student will have same number of markes? if not then do you expect to see blanks or 0 in the empty place? If you know the maximum number of marks column you can simply define all or perhaps you could generate the columns in code behind or by using attached property behavior for better control.

Comment: Yeah every student will have the same marks. Can it only be done in the code behind or is there any way to do in xaml itself?

Comment: xaml may not be able to do that on its own as marks is a type of collection, if you want that then you may have to define some property descriptors to Student class for xaml to be able to discover the properties? would you prefer that approach?

Comment: yeah i think in xaml would be neat.

Comment: There can be an issue with your code. If a record does not have any marks then you will bind to null values. Perhaps IndexOutOfRangeException will be thrown. The rest looks fine.

Comment: as these are binding errors which will produce a null value to the cell. You can optionally define a fallback value in binding to display in place of blanks eg 'N/A' etc., there will not be any error to UI. the above sample is from my tests here.

Answer (score 3):

you can try like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding lstStu}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="list">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Marks}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

if you don't want to display mark in list and you have fixed number of mark,you can do it like this

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="mark1" Binding="{Binding Marks[0]}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="mark2" Binding="{Binding Marks[1]}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use below menioned code

```
Class Student
{
         String Name;
         List<String> Marks;
}


 private ObservableCollection<Student> _student=new ObservableCollection<Student>();

    public ObservableCollection<Student> student
    {
        get { return _student; }
        set { _student = value; }
    }
```

and your Itemsource look like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding student}">
        <DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Marks}"></DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Will it expand the List<Marks> and put it into the columns?

Comment: Sorry i got it. But this will work only for one student what about a List<Student>?

Comment: Write List<Student> inplace of <Student>

Answer (score 1):

In the first place you need to have public properties instead of fields in your model. Like that:

```
public class Student
{
         public String Name {get;set;}
         public List<String> Marks {get;set;}
}
```

Then provide datacontext for the grid. In code behind add something like that:

```
var StudentsList = new List<Student>();
//populate the list.....    
DataContext=StudentsList;
```

The last thing is to bind the DataContext to controls in xaml. Like in the other answers:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                       <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Marks}" />
                </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The datagrid shows a column named "Marks", but in the row it says "Collection".